# What is Apple's equivalent to Adobe After Effects?

Tags: mac, software-recommendation, software, adobe, final-cut-pro

I was wondering, what is Apple's version of After Effects? In the same way that Final Cut Pro is the apple alternative to Adobe Premiere Pro.

Comment: It's kinda Premiere Pro that's the alternative to Final Cut, but who's counting. :)

Comment: @MarcWilson - I admire your loyalty, but in fact Premier came nearly a decade before FCP & was initially designed by people poached from Adobe ;) [and, same as Photoshop, was Mac-only to start with] I have to say, I'm doing more stuff in daVinci these days, I used it last week to test an 8 camera multicam edit, but I can't yet decide which I'd call "best".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple [Motion](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/motion/id434290957?mt=12) but it wouldn't be fair to leave out BlackMagic's [daVinci Fusion](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/uk/products/davinciresolve/fusion)

I couldn't make the call on which to use. I'm just an amateur.

Comment: I'm wondering why your answer is being voted as "not useful". The Mac App Store literally has the description of "Designed for video editors, Motion is a powerful motion graphics tool that makes it easy to create cinematic 2D and 3D titles, fluid transitions, and realistic effects in real time." The last line is literally what I was asking for, which is the Apple visual effects software. Thank you @Tetsujin

Comment: I'd wondered too, but you can't please all the people all the time. Some answers really can be one word answers. I'd even offered an alternative too, as all three 'families' ought to be under consideration by the pro editor [which doesn't really include me, I'm just an enthusiastic amateur ;)

Comment: I've upvoted it!

Comment: I don't think anything can match AE as a 2.5D video animation software. Sure you have plenty 3D programs around that will surpass its capabilities, but AE's versatility and features are outstanding... I have not been using Motion for a long time, but it was like a teenager version back in the day.